# How can I provide a custom second factor of authentication using Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I want to provide my application's users the ability to add a second factor of Authentication and I'm currently using Firebase for logging and signing in new users. Firebase already lets you use a second factor but your only possibility is to send an SMS to a verified phone number. I want to replace this second factor with [Authy OneTouch](https://authy.com/blog/authy-onetouch-modern-authentication-for-any-application/) so I was wondering what's the best practice in this case.

**Right now** here's how I authenticate my users:

1. An user logs in using a form in my client. Under the hood I'm using `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, retrieving the IDToken from Firebase and setting persistence to `NONE`.
2. The client sends a post request to my backend attaching the IdToken and `singOut` immediately after.
3. If the token is valid, the server will provide an `HttpOnly` session cookie storing that token that will be sent along with future requests to my backend to keep track of the user's authentication state.

**How I plan to change my workflow**:

1. Through the profile page, the user may or may not opt-in for the second auth factor.
2. On user opting in I'll send a request to my server and it will call `setCustomUserClaims` to attach a custom `mfa` claim and do the necessary steps to register a new user on Authy.
3. On logging in I access the claim calling `getIdTokenResult` and access `tokenResult.claims.mfa`. If it doesn't exist then the process goes as the previous list. Otherwise I log the user out, ask him/her to go through the second factor, and regularly poll a specific URL that Authy provides to get updates on the status of the second factor challenge.
4. When I detect that the second factor challenge was successfully completed I send a post request to my backend attaching the idToken I got from Firebase and relevant infos I got from Authy's response.
5. The backend verifies if the idToken is valid (to make sure the email-password challenge was previously performed), then proceeds to generate a custom token with Firebase user's `uuid, email, password, mfa-status` using `createCustomToken`, then performs a `signInWithCustomToken` and sets a session cookie in the response.

Is my idea fundamentally correct? In case does Firebase provide a way to customize its default second factor and I just missed it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Firebase Authentications's paid brethren Google Cloud Identity Platform does offer [2FA with SMS](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa#enabling_multi-factor_authentication), neither of them currently provides an option to use/require a custom second factor for authenticating a user.

It's a common request though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it.

Until the feature is added to Firebase itself, the only way you can do something like that is through a [custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth), which allows you (but also requires you) to take control of the auth flow yourself.

Comment: @FrankVanBuffelen: I kinda suspected that, thanks for your input though